# how to store and call a sql query from a table column?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Insert statement below holds details of another Table that has 3 columns (id,ins_dt,text_stuff)

```
INSERT INTO swpurge_config
       (schema
       ,table_name
       ,table_alias
       ,driving_column
       ,deletion_predicate
       ,retention_period_type
       ,retention_period_value)
    VALUES
       ('CUSTOMERS_OWNER'
       ,'LAST_NAMES'
       ,'LN'
       ,'ins_dt'
       ,'WHERE ln.ins_dt < SYSDATE - p_retention_period_value
      AND ora_hash(ln.rowid, 8) = 1'
       ,'month'
       ,'6');
```

**Aim:**
I am essentially trying to add a delete predicate in a varchar2 column. The idea is to call this column in a Procedure which will delete records up to 1000 rows:

```
    PROCEDURE delete_rows
   (
      p_schema                 IN VARCHAR2
     ,p_table_name             IN VARCHAR2
     ,p_table_alias            in varchar2
     ,p_retention_period_value IN VARCHAR2
     ,p_delete_predicate       IN VARCHAR2
   ) IS
      v_sql varchar2 (32000);
      v_row_limit pls_integer (1000);
   BEGIN

    v_sql := 'delete from ' || p_schema ||'.'|| table_name ||p_table_alias
     'older than '|| p_retention_period_value || p_delete_predicate;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);

   END delete_rows;
```

Not sure about 2 things: 
1. How to store the sql where clause in a table column?
2. How to execute the where clause as a statement in the procedure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are talking about *Dynamic SQL*.

You can just store it inside `VARCHAR2` in string format. then retrieve it

```
 select deletion_predicate into v_sql from  swpurge_config where ...
```

then

```
v_sql := "SELECT ...... FRom .... " || v_sql;
```

finally execute it

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
```

if your sql statement also includes parameters then

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str
    using param1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, the reason behind retrieving SQL statement from SWPURGE_CONFIG table is so that i can add multiple delete statements of several other tables and store it in config table. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Also i have another procedure with a select statement that gets records from swpurge_config table.

Comment: You cannot get answer to multiple questions under single thread. This breaks usability of SO. If you have new question, please consider to open new thread. And If this answer solves your specific problem, consider to mark it as answer so the community can also benefit from it. Good Luck